# On slick or LWJGL, how do you display many lines of Unicode font fast?

Tags: opengl, unicode, fonts, frame-rate, slick2d

I'm having trouble displaying Unicode font on opengl. I need to show like 20 lines of Unicode font text on my game and it has to be dynamically loaded(since the text is Japanese). The only unicode font library I could found was slick but rendering is so slow...

Is there any way to display many lines of unicode font text on the fly without sacrificing FPS? No JOGL, I'm using slick and LWJGL right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for clarity, can you define "so slow" so we have an idea of what your rendering constraints are?

As a possible solution you could render the text to off screen textures with alpha, and then draw the textures on screen. If the text is going to be exactly the same every time you could also just use static images with the pre-rendered text (e.g. .PNG files).

Comment: Showing 20 lines of unicode text is as slow as showing 100x 256x256 texture on screen(not kidding). I was hoping there was easy way around, like opengl unicode library